# Shell script to delete records from Oracle DB table

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

I have a situation where I need to run a shell script every 30 days to delete records from Oracle database table.

The table has a column 'updated_date'. I need to write a query to delete records where 'updated_date' less than current date minus 30 days.

In Java I can do it comfortably. How to calculate the dynamic date and pass it to SQL query in Unix shell script.

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the delete statement suggested by Littlefoot to utilize the system date from within the database.

But, since you asked -

> How to calculate the dynamic date and pass it to SQL query in Unix
>   shell script,

This is how you can do it.

First, use the date command to get the current date in `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format.

```
export dt=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

You may then use the date variable within your shell script in `sqlplus`.

```
sqlplus -s userid/passwd@db_server<<EOF
delete from yourtable
      where updated_date < DATE '${dt}' - 30;
commit;
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```
delete from your_table
where updated_date < trunc(sysdate) - 30;
```

SYSDATE is a function that returns current date (and time - that's why I used TRUNC function which will remove time component). It also means that you don't have to *calculate date and pass it to SQL query* - Oracle know it itself.

Though, note that SYSDATE shows *database server* date, so - if you work on different time zones, you might need to consider that fact.

Also, "minus 30 days": is it always 30 days, or did you actually mean "minus 1 month"? If so, you'd change the condition to

```
where updated_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1)
```

and it'll take care about number of days in a month (30, 31; including February as well as leap years).

Comment: Nitpicking: `trunc()` does not "remove" the time component, it just sets it to `00:00:00`

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse; during my short life here on SO, I've been quite often *nitpicked*. Hopefully, someday I'll learn enough not to be (that often, that is :)).